# Android ADB not running on windows showing The application was unable to start 0xc000007b

Tags: android, windows, adb

I am using a Windows 8.1 system which is not having updates for a longer period of time. I have successfully installed Android studio for flutter and everything works perfectly but when I tried to run ADB this error comes.

**"The application was unable to start 0xc000007b. Click ok to close the application"**

Searched all over the internet for answers wasted 2 days of time. In internet everything shows things related to 64 bit 32 bit issues and replacing with an older ADB both ways i tried but no help or didn't got the accurate version which will work on this system.

**********UPDATE**********

Had gone through revisions of ADB and got this changelog that is updated as an anwswer for guys who will be having the same scenario this issue willl normally occur who turn off automatic updates or set connection as metered.

Answer (score 0):

This is showing the error because Android ADB had an update for the revision 28.0.2 (March 2019), after this release ADB needs windows to have this update (KB2999226) for running. This will be occurring to systems that disabled automatic windows update. For me, it was on Windows 8.1 pro 64. I have spent my 2 days on this. Got different solutions on the internet that vary from DLL files to .net, visual c++, and DirectX, none of them helped. Please do this update as this is needed for the newer ADB to work properly.

[Android revision change notification about this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#2802_march_2019)

[Link to the update for windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)